# Is there a way to specify that the user uses the native camera and not any other apps.(Cordova/Ionic)?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

So I am currently using ionic native's camera plugin to allow the user to take photos. But I want to be able to specify that the user uses the device's native camera function and not any other apps available on the appstore/playstore(like beautify).

I understand that the camera plugin uses the camera specified in the default settings of the phone but is it possible to specify that he uses the device's native camera app?

Currently this is the system information for the environment that I am developing this app in.

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0

Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.4

Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.30

Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.16

Node Version: v4.4.7

thanks a lot in advance!